# Office 2010 and Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange, outlook, outlook-2010

I have office 2010 and Exchange 2010. I have send as permissions and Full access rights to a few mailboxes (System and Spam boxes mainly) with Office 2010 it adds in the additional mailboxes by default if you have full access etc. I use my desktop mainly for Mail etc, but sometimes need to use a laptop for console config etc and check mail. My problem is that it adds in the additional mailboxes in on the laptop as well.

I suppose my question is can I stop outlook 2010 adding in the mailboxes on the laptop client.

Comment: Manually configure Outlook instead of using automatic configuration.

Comment: When adding the send as permissions ln exchange it adds the mailbox. It's a domain setting and I do don't want to turn it off as a work around. I think It's a local registry edit that is needed as when in additional mailbox options the boxes are not showed.

Comment: So you're saying that when you configure Outlook manually to open your mailbox it opens the other mailbox as well?

Comment: Corect this is a feature of office 2010 and exchange 2010. You can disable it globaly but I do not want to do this. I just want to stop one client doing the auto adding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of research this is a new feature of Exchange 2010 SP1 and is referred by Microsoft as Additional Mailbox Auto Mapping in Exchange 2010 SP1. This is supposed to be a nice feature by Microsoft to stop Sysadmins needing to visit desktops to add additional mailboxes. To disable this you need to install SP2 and remove the full access rights of a user and add them back in.